# display the details on click with firebase

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I want to display the details of the address by clicking on the elements by the firebase key. I can do it with the id but not the key of the push. Thank you for your return because I do not know how to do it with the key

**my address table**

[image: my address table]

**service adresse**

```
 getSingleAdresse(id: number){
        return new Promise(
          (resolve, reject) =>{
            firebase.database().ref('/adresse/' +id).once('value').then(
              (data) => {
                resolve(data.val());
              }, (error) => {
                reject(error);
              }
            );
          }
        );
      }
```

**list page.html**

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let item of adresses | keyvalue ; let i = index" (click)="onViewAdresse(i)">
         <div><b>{{item.value.prenom}} {{item.value.nom}}</b></div>
</ion-card>
```

**Single adress.ts ( the page to retrieve the elements )**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.adresse = new Adresse ('','', '', '', '', '');
    const id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
    this.adresseService.getSingleAdresse(+id).then(
      (adresse: Adresse) => {
        this.adresse = adresse;
      }
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: If there are multiple child nodes under a user's node, which one do you want to show?

Comment: the one on which the user will click

Comment: if he he on the element that at node
-LsRa-OFBddC25NnxyFu (the information is displayed) the same for the other nodes. thank you

Comment: OK. I that case you'll need to capture the ID of the node they clicked on, and pass that in to database loading code: `firebase.database().ref('/adresse/' +id).child(idTheyClickedOn)`

Comment: thanks I'm new to Firebase and I'm trying to do so much. I do not know how to use the code because it gives it error. I replace .once ('value') with .child ()
Or there is another way to retrieve the information from the key

Comment: I can send the key in url http: // localhost: 8100 / single-address / -LsXMDGgFFxDSJfNRnI

possible to retrieve info from this key

Comment: You shouldn't **replace** the `once(...)` call, but just add a `child(...)` call to reach the lower level in your JSON tree.

Comment: i tried to do some research on the child but i do not see too much. you have an example